# web scraping, back in stock notification

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to set up a Python script that tells me if a product is back in stock. currently it scrapes the url below and parses the relevant section of the website but i can't figure out how to take this output variable i have called stock and store it as another variable called stock_history and then run another line asking if stock is equal or not to stock_history

i'm also getting an EOL while scanning string literal error while trying to store html data in stock_history. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
now = datetime.now()
#enter website address
url = requests.get('https://shop.bitmain.com/antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'html')

stock = (soup.find("div", "buy-now-bar-con"))

stock_history = '<div class="buy-now-bar-con">
<a class="current" href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?flag=overview">Overview</a>
<a href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?flag=specifications">Specification</a>
<a href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?flag=gallery">Gallery</a>
<a class="btn-buy-now" href="javascript:;" style="background:#a7a4a4; cursor:not-allowed;" target="_self" title="sold out!">Coming soon</a>
</div>'


print(stock)

if stock == stock_history 
    print("still not in stock")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the EOL stands for "End of Line" and you'll typically get this error if python doesn't like how you've defined a string or have used some wonky characters. To avoid this you can triple quote your string in your original code like so:

```
stock_history = '''<div class="buy-now-bar-con">
<a class="current" href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?
flag=overview">Overview</a>
<a href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?
flag=specifications">Specification</a>
<a href="antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?flag=gallery">Gallery</a>
<a class="btn-buy-now" href="javascript:;" style="background:#a7a4a4; 
cursor:not-allowed;" target="_self" title="sold out!">Coming soon</a>
</div>'''
```

This is ugly, so I did away with that big string because it isn't necessary. The only information you should want to obtain from your `stock` variable is whether or not the product is sold out or not. To do this, you can convert the `bs4.element.Tag` into a `str` type and use regular expressions to check for the presence of the "sold out!" substring. Regular expressions really do come in handy wherever you're doing Scraping, working with text data, or performing any form of XML or HTML parsing so I encourage you to read up on them.

More info: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

You can easily test python regex captures here: https://pythex.org/

Here's the altered code, which does what you were trying to get it to do.

```
import re
import csv
import requests
from datetime import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stock_check(url):
    """Function checks url for 'sold out!' substring in url.content"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml") #Need to use lxml parser
    stock = soup.find("div", "buy-now-bar-con") #Check the html tags for sold out/coming soon info.
    stock_status = re.findall(r"(sold out!)", str(stock)) #Returns list of captured substring if exists.
    return stock_status[0] # returns "sold out!" from soup string.

now = datetime.now()

url = requests.get('https://shop.bitmain.com/antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm')

if stock_check(url) == "sold out!":
    print(str(now) + ": Still not in stock...")
else:
    print(str(now) + ": Now in stock!")
```

Try it out and let me know if you have any questions!

EDIT: OP asked how to periodically check webpage and include e-mail notification. A few things needed to be changed from the original solution such as setting `userAgent` information in the `requests headers` field. Also made a switch to `html.parser` instead of `lxml` for the `BeautifulSoup` object to properly deal with javascript in the `url.content`.

```
import re
import time
import smtplib
import requests
from datetime import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def stock_check(url):
    """Checks url for 'sold out!' substring in buy-now-bar-con"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser") #Need to use lxml parser
    stock = soup.find("div", "buy-now-bar-con") #Check the html tags for sold out/coming soon info.
    stock_status = re.findall(r"sold out!", str(stock)) #Returns list of captured substring if exists.
    return stock_status # returns "sold out!" from soup string.

def send_email(address, password, message):
    """Send an e-mail to yourself!"""
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) #e-mail server
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(address,password) #login
    message = str(message) #message to email yourself
    server.sendmail(address,address,message) #send the email through dedicated server
    return

def stock_check_listener(url, address, password, run_hours):
    """Periodically checks stock information."""
    listen = True # listen boolean
    start = datetime.now() # start time
    while(listen): #while listen = True, run loop
        if "sold out!" in stock_check(url): #check page
            now = datetime.now()
            print(str(now) + ": Not in stock.")
        else:
            message = str(now) + ": NOW IN STOCK!"
            print(message)
            send_email(address, password, message)
            listen = False

        duration = (now - start)
        seconds = duration.total_seconds()
        hours = int(seconds/3600)
        if hours >= run_hours: #check run time
            print("Finished.")
            listen = False

        time.sleep(30*60) #Wait N minutes to check again.    
    return

if __name__=="__main__":

    #Set url and userAgent header for javascript issues.
    page = "https://shop.bitmain.com/antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'}

    #URL request.
    url = requests.get(url=page,
                       headers=headers)

    #Run listener to stream stock checks.
    address = "user@gmail.com" #your email
    password = "user.password" #your email password
    stock_check_listener(url=url,
                         address=address,
                         password=password,
                         run_hours=1)
```

Now, the program will initiate a `while` loop which periodically requests information from the webpage. You can set the timeout (in hours) by changing the `run_hours` variable. You can also set the sleep/wait time (in minutes) by changing `N` within `stock_check_listener`. I used `gmail` in this case, and if you receive an error when e-mailing yourself then you will need to follow this link: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps, and allow less secure apps (your python program) to access your gmail account.

Comment: how would i run this in a loop with a reasonable break (x seconds) and then email myself when NOW in stock! = True

Comment: @Twiggy I'm not sure what you need it for, but you could try building a while loop that checks the stock every hour or so. You would need to incorporate a `time.sleep()` step after each `stock_check(url)` request and then could potentially leave it running in a console or terminal window. The condition in which your while loop breaks is up to you, you could give it a time duration based on the time you started it. Also, if you need help with it I can look into it.